# Jquery trigger click on button in webform doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have code in Webform aspx page that contains lots of comments with button that has class "like". When I click some of this buttons I have to trigger click on asp Button control which contains all the back-end code for liking some comment. With this jquery code :

```
$(".like").click(function () {
    var button = this;
    var id = $(this).parent().find(".comment-id").val();
    $("[id$='commentID']").val(id);
    if ($(button).find("i").hasClass("fa-star-o")) {
        $("[id$='btnLikeComment']").click();
    }
    else {
        $("[id$='btnUnlikeComment']").click();
    }
});
```

the click event of asp Button never happens. Can anyone tell me where's the problem ?

Edit: Here's the code from the asp Buttons controls:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLikeComment" runat="server" Style="display: none;" Text="Button" OnClick="btnLikeComment_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUnlikeComment" runat="server" Style="display: none;" Text="Button" OnClick="btnUnlikeComment_Click" />
```

Comment: there are a number of issues here, but before we can help you you should post the ASP:Button code

Comment: @fross any console errors?

Comment: no, when I paste this line of code in console :
$("[id$='btnLikeComment']").click();
the button click event is triggered.

Comment: I think @Webruster refers to errors that may happen prior to the click calls. If any, they would prevent code execution going further.

Comment: No I don't have any errors on console when i click the button, I checked it with debug and the code is executing successfully before triggering the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added event.preventDefault(); before triggering the click of asp button and this works fine, the click event is triggered successfully.

```
function likeComment(button) {
    var id = $(button).parent().find(".comment-id").val();
    $("[id$='commentID']").val(id);
    event.preventDefault();
    $("[id$='btnLikeComment']").trigger('click');
}

<button class='...' onclick='likeComment(this)'><i class='...'></i></button>
```

Comment: Good job simplifying you requirement so that you are able to use an HTML button rather than an ASP button. That is all you really needed to do. I have to add that if you had been clear about what it was you were trying to do. My answer and others would have pointed you in the right direction from the get go. My answer would have and did get you there but you say "I need the attribute onclick for executing code-behind function". Turns out that wasn't the case, and my comment made you realize that?

Comment: I still use aps button with code-hehind function. The asp Buttons are still the same : 
<asp:Button ID="btnLikeComment" runat="server" Style="display: none;" OnClick="btnLikeComment_Click" />

"When I click some of this buttons(this were html buttons with class like) I have to trigger click on asp Button control which contains all the back-end code for liking some comment".
So I have a lot html buttons for each comment, but just one aps button for writing the like in database. Maybe I wasn't clear enough when I asked the question, but thanks for your help.

Comment: I see. The scenario you are describing now, explains what you are trying to do. 
Now that I understand I would have advised you to use Jquery AJAX call do achieve all the functionality in one function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encapsulate JS like this

```
   function LikeBtnClick() {
       var button = this;
       var id = $(this).parent().find(".comment-id").val();
       $("[id$='commentID']").val(id);
       if ($(button).find("i").hasClass("fa-star-o")) {
           $("[id$='btnLikeComment']").click();
       }
       else {
           $("[id$='btnUnlikeComment']").click();
       }
   }
```

And Then Use the asp.net attribute onclientClick

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLikeComment" runat="server" Style="display: none;" Text="Button" OnClientClick="LikeBtnClick" OnClick="btnLikeComment_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUnlikeComment" runat="server" Style="display: none;" Text="Button" OnClientClick="LikeBtnClick" OnClick="btnUnlikeComment_Click" />
```

Comment: This didn't helped me. On the asp.net button I need the attribute onclick for executing code-behind function, and I added the encapsulated js on buttons in every comment:
<button class='...' onclick='likeComment(this)'><i class='...'></i></button>
but this still doesn't work.

Comment: You can do both client side and server side calls. I re-added you server side calls. However it all depends on what you are really trying to accomplish with each client side calls are usually reserved for display and the server side calls are usually for some Database interaction and require a post back which will make your client side calls obsolete.
you should try to be clear about what you are trying to accomplish, then it would be easier to help you.

Comment: thanks for your help, I found solution that works for now.